# Is there an alternative in Python for quadprog()

Tags: python, matlab, machine-learning, svm

I am working on SVM and looking to solve the quadratic programming problem. We have a function in MATLAB quadprog() but is there any alternative in python. 
I installed cvxopt but I am getting an error ValueError: Rank(A) < p or Rank([P; A; G]) < n while minimizing.

Comment: What about [scipy.optimize.minimize](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html)? Most used methods are CG and (L)BGFS. Thus, the best algorithm to use often depends on what data you are processing (ill-conditioned problem, correlated data...). I can develop if you need

Answer (score 0):

Now there is: look at `qpsolvers` which provide a unified quadprog-like interface to many existing solvers. See [here](https://pypi.org/project/qpsolvers/)